# unable to remove duplication when composing tests

Tags: clojure, clojure.test

I am unable to remove duplication inside a `clojure.test` test.

Suppose I have multiple implementations for the same abstraction:

```
(defn foo1 [] ,,,)
(defn foo2 [] ,,,)
(defn foo3 [] ,,,)
```

and I also have a test that all implementations should pass:

```
(defn test-impl [foo]
  (is (= ,,, (foo))))
```

I can now create a `clojure.test` test that checks all the implementations in a single step:

```
(deftest test-all-impls
  (test-impl foo1)
  (test-impl foo2)
  (test-impl foo3))
```

All is good; running the tests in the REPL I get:

```
(run-tests)

Testing user

Ran 1 tests containing 3 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
=> {:test 1, :pass 3, :fail 0, :error 0, :type :summary}
```

I now want to modify `test-all-impls` to remove the duplication of having to invoke `test-impl` explicitly for each of the implementations. It occurs to me to modify `test-all-impls` as follows:

```
(deftest test-all-impls
  (for [foo [foo1 foo2 foo3]] (test-impl foo))
```

Hmm, now not all is good; in the REPL I get:

```
(run-tests)

Testing user

Ran 1 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
=> {:test 1, :pass 0, :fail 0, :error 0, :type :summary}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get around the lazyness of for, use doseq instead:

```
(deftest test-all-impls
  (doseq [foo [foo1 foo2 foo3]] (test-impl foo))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is to convert the result into a vector, which will force the `for` loop to run:

```
(deftest test-all-impls
  (vec (for [foo [foo1 foo2 foo3]] (test-impl foo))))
```